# NFC task for BOTH tag entry and exit

Tags: nfc, car-dock

Since picking up a few NFC tags I've been experimenting with automation apps to run tasks for certain contexts (e.g. Car dock).

The apps I've tried (e.g. [Trigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher)) are great at running tasks when the tag appears but I've yet to find one to trigger events when the tag is removed.

The car dock scenario would involve:

- Tag entry

  - Wifi off
  - Brightness auto
  - Lock screen off
- Tag exit

  - Reverse above changes

Setting the phone up for the drive is great but very annoying that I can't  jump out my car and chuck my phone in a pocket without toggling settings off.

I'm aware that some of the apps have a 'toggle' mode where tapping the same tag twice can run another set of tasks. This is not ideal.

Comment: Have you considered the mighty [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)? I don't have an NFC or even a Car to test it, but it's very powerful so you may give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding (I was interested in the same sort of thing) is that there is no event fired when an NFC tag is removed. So the only way to do this would be a check at regular intervals to see if the NFC tag is still connected, and I'm not sure that even that is possible.